# Spring boot unable to create multiple rabbit connection factories

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I am trying to connect to and consume from two different clusters of rabbitmq using a spring boot app via xml. It works well when a single rabbit:connection-factory bean is created in the application context. However, when the second one is added, it fails to start the application with the error **"Parameter 1 of method rabbitListenerContainerFactory in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:"**. How do I go about creating different factories per cluster? Please suggest an alternative way of doing this, if it's not the right approach?

Here is the xml snippet:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="firstConnectionFactory" connection-factory="firstSpringConnectionFactory"  />
<rabbit:connection-factory id="secondConnectionFactory" connection-factory="secondSpringConnectionFactory"/>
<bean id="firstSpringConnectionFactory"
class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="useSSL" value="${rabbitmq.ssl.enabled}" />
    <property name="host" value="${rabbitmq.first.host}"/>
    <property name="virtualHost" value="${rabbitmq.vhost}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${rabbitmq.cluster.port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${rabbitmq.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${rabbitmq.first.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="secondSpringConnectionFactory"
class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="useSSL" value="${rabbitmq.ssl.enabled}" />
    <property name="host" value="${rabbitmq.second.host}"/>
    <property name="virtualHost" value="${rabbitmq.vhost}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${rabbitmq.cluster.port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${rabbitmq.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${rabbitmq.second.password}"/>
</bean>
```

And the listener container code:

```
ConnectionFactory cf = rabbitConnectionFactory;//One of the connnection factories will be injected here from app context
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(cf);
container.setConcurrentConsumers(count);
container.addQueueNames(queueName);
container.setMessageListener(listener);
container.start();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't rely on the Spring Boot here and don't use Spring AMQP annotation support I suggest you to [exclude](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration) `RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` from auto-configuration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class})

spring.autoconfigure.exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration
```

If you still need `@RabbitListener` somewhere in other place of your project, you only have a choice to build all the `@EnableRabbit` infrastructure [manually](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven).

Comment: Thanks @Artem, I am able to get past the error by excluding the class RabbitAutoConfiguration @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: sure, I am going to run some tests and see if nothing breaks because of this change and accept your answer:)

Comment: how do I properly use RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration then?

Comment: You should not use it: the `@EnableRabbit` does the stuff for you